# How to create different pages for different users with google appengine

Tags: python

To better understand Google appengine (GAE) I have decided to build an exercise tracking website for my mother as well as a way to further enhance my skills. This would enables the user to log in and keep a record of all the exercises they would attempted or plan to do over the course of the week kind of like a diary. I know you can find apps but I'm learning here.

The problem I am having is I want the users to log in and find only the details related to them. Instead of logging in and seeing everybody details and by everyone I mean anyone who has used the app to store their exercises details in the datastore. It like when you log into facebook you see only your details not everyone who has used facebook.

I cannot seen to find anything on how enable user to see only their information anywhere.

## UPDATE

So instead of building an exercise tracking I decided to build a job tracker for my brother as he requested it and for myself as a learning tool to improve my programming skills (I plan to add even more functionally to the site such as the ability the see the job history for the last few months and some javascript to improve the look and feel of the site). I even managed to link the database to user name thanks dartdog for suggesting it.

But now I have another problem the data is not persistence. By that I mean after the user logs in adds their details in the job timetable, the user can look up the details their added. But after a few hours the data is gone but not the user login in details only the content they posted. Kind makes for a poor application if the data is not persistence.

ps
Language of choice python. Here the link to my jobtracker app.

[my jobtracker application](http://www.personaljobtracker.appspot.com/login)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is quite generic,you can tie a user id to a search field on the database.. And that can do it. Anything else will be an enhancement on that theme. You will have to learn to program in the language of your choice. There are several data storage methods, including MYSQL that can handle this with the right code on your part.

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I am using python as the language of choice to interact with GAE. It was that or Java. Interesting suggestion I am going to attempt to tie the user name to the database. Once I figured out how. I gave you an up vote but unfortunately I do not have enough votes to make show in the public interface

Comment: Ok, now that you have specified a bit more you may find some guidance with a Python framework, take a look at Flask..